# How to select rows before the column value changes in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a help desk project in which we get tickets on some issues related to the project. I am showing the status of a ticket for each day of current week as per below image.

For example, the arrow shows the total number of tickets still open until this week's Monday.

[image]

The sql query is like this,

```
declare @day datetime
declare @maxdate datetime
set @maxdate = getdate()
set @day = Convert(Varchar(10),DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0),110)
truncate table Tickets_Until_Current_Day
while  @day <= @maxdate
begin
insert into Tickets_Until_Current_Day
select convert(varchar(20),datename(dw,@day)), count(*) Total_Open_Tickets 
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL.1','DSN=SQLitehgq','Select * from tickets') AS a 
where ticket_createdDate < @day + 1
and [status] = 'open'
set @day = @day + 1
end
```

Now suppose 5 tickets are closed on Tuesday which were created on Monday, then the number that arrow represents becomes 25 because the status in the table is now **closed** for those tickets.

But I want to show the same number throughout the week so that we can know how many tickets were really open at the end of Monday. e.g., If 30 tickets were open on Monday, at the end of the week, it must show 30 only.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can remove `and [status] = 'open' ` as createdDate condition alone will take care of it.

Comment: Yes. But that will return all the created tickets so far. I tried it and it returns a huge number. I just want open tickets so far.